# can i implement the flutter dependency injection in flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing the flutter project with monorepo(melos).

One package is dependent on another
project1-|app|features(patient, etc.)|utilities
project2-|

so since the patient feature do not have the main function. so where do I call the sl initialization? In the 'app' OR in the 'project'??